# How can I install a version of Windows 10 on a Lenovo N21 Chromebook?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, chromebook

I have been wanting to wipe Chrome OS and install Windows 10 on my Chromebook so that it will be better for me to program. I have googled many times, but many of the solutions are outdated. Is there any updated way to install a copy of Windows 10 on a Chromebook? If so, I would be glad for some help.

Comment: Most likely not possible. If the specs is correct, Lenovo N21 only have 16GB of storage space. Windows 10 probably won't fit.

Comment: The team at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/) posted a tutorial about this less than a week ago.  Personally, it seems like a lot of time and effort to devote towards something that still might not work too gracefully despite your best efforts, but here it is:  [How to Install Windows on a Chromebook](http://www.howtogeek.com/278953/how-to-install-windows-on-a-chromebook/)

Comment: Yes thanks I saw their post, but just wanted to make sure to see if anyone here managed to do it. This Lenovo only has 2 GB of RAM.